# Set math and text fonts independently in Beamer (using PDFLaTeX)

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

I am working on a Beamer presentation, and I would like to use sans serif font (CMBright) for text, and a serif font (Computer Modern) for maths. Sans serif maths looks pretty ugly to me.

Beamer default settings are sans serif maths and text :

[image]

I found I can switch maths font to serif with the line

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

which yields (see MWE1 below)

[image]

Now maths look nice, but I would like to change the default text font to CMBright. 
I tried to naively combine those two lines (see MWE2)

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{cmbright}
```

but is gives me everything in CBMright (ie sans serif)

[image]

I seemed to find some people using LuaTeX or related systems, but I would like to find a solution using PDFLaTeX only.

More generally, is there a way to set the maths and text fonts independently using PDFLaTeX, ie to any font different than CM and CMBright ?

---

MWE1

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

MWE2

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmbr}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    Some text, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! How do we know one has to refer to CMBright as `cmbr` in this context ? Where can I find the abbreviation to use in case I want another font ?

Comment: Go into the directory of `cmbright.sty`. There you find files like `t1cmbr.fd`. This is the file definition file (.fd) of family `cmbr` in T1 font encoding

Comment: But `\usepackage{cmbright}` does a lot more settings than just `\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmbr}`. How to keep these?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Unfortunately,  `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` has no effect if cmbright is loaded as a package. (As shown by OP.)

Comment: run it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Answer (score 5):

It might be late for this answer but I found a workaround for your problem.
Simply put `sefif` and `professionalfont` into the preamble like this:

```
\documentclass[serif,professionalfont]{beamer}
```

and then load your font package (in my case it is iwona)

```
\usepackage{iwona}
```

You do NOT need to use

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

I've tested on Overleaf with PDFLatex Compiler and TexLive2019. Hope others will find this useful.

[image: Different Body text font and Math font]

Comment: Please note that the `serif` and `professionalfont` class options are obsolete. You should use the font themes of the same name instead.