# Change math font to sans-serif default in Beamer metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamer-metropolis

I am using the Beamer metropolis theme, and I would like to change the math font to the default sans-serif font in Beamer presentations, while keeping the text font to be Fira Sans. Is there a simple way to do so (preferably in PDFLaTeX over XeLaTeX)?

I have tried similar approaches as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403734/beamer-metropolis-theme-recommend-a-math-font-that-matches-with-fira/403738#403738) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34265/how-to-get-beamer-math-to-look-like-article-math), but neither seems to work for me...

Comment: Maybe you could also try this one : [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198387/set-math-and-text-fonts-independently-in-beamer-using-pdflatex).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you provided some code to show explicitly what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the use with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{FiraSans}
\def\mathfamilydefault{cmss}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
text

\[
x^2 abc
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I don't recommend mixing font families like this)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the bold-face Fira fonts (e.g., in the frame titles) are not rendered correctly in pdfLaTeX (seems double-thick...)? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Hilbert Please ask a question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem